# Can I use SQLite to share data among different applications?

Tags: sqlite, embedded

Can I use SQLite as a database to which 2 or more applications connect?

I.e. can I use it to share data among different applications?

Comment: see also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060772/sqlite3-concurrent-access

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes.

From [the FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5):

> **Can multiple applications or multiple instances of the same application access a single database file at the same time?**
>
> Multiple processes can have the same database open at the same time.
>   Multiple processes can be doing a SELECT at the same time. But only
>   one process can be making changes to the database at any moment in
>   time, however.
>
> SQLite uses reader/writer locks to control access to the database.
>   (Under Win95/98/ME which lacks support for reader/writer locks, a
>   probabilistic simulation is used instead.) But use caution: this
>   locking mechanism might not work correctly if the database file is
>   kept on an NFS filesystem. This is because fcntl() file locking is
>   broken on many NFS implementations. You should avoid putting SQLite
>   database files on NFS if multiple processes might try to access the
>   file at the same time. On Windows, Microsoft's documentation says that
>   locking may not work under FAT filesystems if you are not running the
>   Share.exe daemon. People who have a lot of experience with Windows
>   tell me that file locking of network files is very buggy and is not
>   dependable. If what they say is true, sharing an SQLite database
>   between two or more Windows machines might cause unexpected problems.
>
> We are aware of no other embedded SQL database engine that supports as
>   much concurrency as SQLite. SQLite allows multiple processes to have
>   the database file open at once, and for multiple processes to read the
>   database at once. When any process wants to write, it must lock the
>   entire database file for the duration of its update. But that normally
>   only takes a few milliseconds. Other processes just wait on the writer
>   to finish then continue about their business. Other embedded SQL
>   database engines typically only allow a single process to connect to
>   the database at once.
>
> However, client/server database engines (such as PostgreSQL, MySQL, or
>   Oracle) usually support a higher level of concurrency and allow
>   multiple processes to be writing to the same database at the same
>   time. This is possible in a client/server database because there is
>   always a single well-controlled server process available to coordinate
>   access. If your application has a need for a lot of concurrency, then
>   you should consider using a client/server database. But experience
>   suggests that most applications need much less concurrency than their
>   designers imagine.
>
> When SQLite tries to access a file that is locked by another process,
>   the default behavior is to return SQLITE_BUSY. You can adjust this
>   behavior from C code using the sqlite3_busy_handler() or
>   sqlite3_busy_timeout() API functions.